# How to set up a Schedule Trigger that runs daily on weekdays

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've got a Schedule Trigger set up to run daily, but I thought I'd heard that I could set it up to run every weekday instead. Is that possible?

[image]

Here are the settings at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your interval to once weekly, this will enable the option to select specific days:

[image: Recurrence trigger in Logic Apps]